# Why I can't see the comments while editing a question of mine?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've just noticed that on Math.SE and Ell.SE (and now here on Meta.SE), if I edit a question of mine I can't see the comments below, in the edit window. If I also want to see the comments, I have to open the question in another window too, not in editing mode.

This does not happen, e.g., on Academia.SE, where if I edit a question I can see the comments in the edit window, as usual below the question.

Is this behaviour site-specific? Or is it reputation-dependent?

Of course, for faster editing, it would be useful, everywhere, to have the comments in the same window (assuming no dual monitor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because on the sites where you have 2k+ rep (1k+ on beta sites), when you click "edit", the inline editor opens, i.e. in the same window (so yes, rep dependent). The window remains containing all the comments, answers, etc, what has been in it.

Until that rep, you are presented with another editor, in a separate window. However, it has some tips one editing.

You can still access the non-inline editor by clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-edit, or use the inline editor anywhere by installing this [user script](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8587-always-edit-inline/code).

Comment: Thank you, I've installed the user script. Nonetheless, I think that SE should take into account the whole network profile, because if one has 2k+ rep on one site, probably doesn't need the editing tips on other sites as well.